# Perlbal Reproxy with Remote Host

Tags: web-services, configuration, reverse-proxy

why would perlbal's reproxying give me a `503` for any remote url?

```
X-REPROXY-URL: /path/to/a/local/file.jpg = working
X-REPROXy-URL: http://a-public-file-in-an-s3-bucket.jpg = HTTP 503
```

my perlbal conf looks like:

```
CREATE POOL test_pool
    POOL test_pool ADD 127.0.0.1:8888
    POOL test_pool ADD 127.0.0.1:8889

CREATE SERVICE balancer
    SET listen          = 0.0.0.0:80
    SET role            = reverse_proxy
    SET pool            = test_pool
    SET persist_client  = on
    SET persist_backend = on
    SET verify_backend  = on
    SET enable_reproxy  = true

ENABLE balancer
```

and i know im setting the header properly, because, as i said, it works for local files and urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like perlbal doesn't deal well with urls like "bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com". changing the url to "s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/" works.